# Can I travel to the UAE while working remotely for my non-UAE (USA) employer?

Tags: usa, work, uae

Planning to visit Dubai, UAE for a month while working remotely for my US employer. I will be on a 30-day tourist visa in the UAE. Any issues to look out for? I've been browsing through lots of websites, but can't find an official UAE-govt link that mentions anything about not being allowed to work in the UAE (remotely for a non-UAE employer).

Can anyone confirm that this would be okay, and back it up with official guidance/documents?

Comment: I think the UAE has fairly recently introduced a remote worker visa, which might be indicative of the official stance on this topic https://u.ae/en/information-and-services/visa-and-emirates-id/types-of-visa/remote-work-visas

Comment: I don't think you will find anything official - but the reality is if you aren't working for a UAE based employer and you don't overstay your visit visa you won't have any issues.